# How to write installable package in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have set of code in php. I need to write down a shell script to put the file into workspace to run. Can you please help me how to write down a shell script?

Thanks in advance  - sri

Answer (score 0):

Check the following resources to help you write scripts:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/
http://linuxcommand.org/